# How can I remove / from favicon.ico/ on apache

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}  !\.(php|html?|jpg|gif|css|js|png|jpeg|JPG|PNG|ico)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)([^/])$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1$2/ [L,R=301]
```

I add auto slash end of my links except below file extentions. That does not work only for favicon.ico

When I try to open my favicon on browser added by apache "/" to end of link like example.com/favicon.ico/ so it is not valid source and giving 404.

Why and how can I solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

You can test if the request is a file:

```
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} !-f
RewriteRule (.*)/? $1/ [L,R=301]
```

this rule mean, if it is not a file redirect to same request path and add / at then end (if the / does not already exist)